# is there a reason to not use cython everywhere?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I learned cython an hour ago, i changed ~10 lines out of thousands of lines in my code and i already got an absurd speed improvement on something that wasn't even my main bottleneck according to the profiler (but still called millions of times).

And the cython report still show pretty much everything in the cythonized code in yellow. (which mean it's not optimal, yet, as far as i know)

this is what i changed, everything else is still "as-is" :

```
@cython.freelist(32)
cdef class Vector:
    cdef public double x, y

    def __cinit__(self, double x=0, double y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    ... (many other methods i didn't touch yet)
```

is there a reason / use-case to not use cython everywhere and everytime you create a class ?

Comment: its more effort. Not my much but its enough to not change the norm

Comment: It's all about finding that balance between speed and ease of use. Python is really easy to use but not really fast, Cython is really fast but harder to use.

Comment: the most scary part is that you're probably correct ...and that leave me speechless.i expected something like "it's bugged, it doesn't work with django, it's not always faster, portability, ..."

Comment: A good deal of Python's popularity has to do with how little actual computer science you need to know in order to start building things. This kind of naturally lends itself to Cython not being used everywhere, as there's an invisible knowledge gap. If you cut your teeth on Python, you likely don't know what you don't know, which puts Cython several steps away instead of just 1.

Comment: I don't know much about Cython, but I suspect the answer is that it's a similar reason why people don't use C instead of Python; there are ways to write in C while calling some Python libraries. It's just a scale of fast-to-write vs. fast-to-run, and people prefer fast-to-write in many situations because the running time of most programs is negligible.

Comment: @Oso i kind of get it. but, i learned python 3 weeks ago to play with AI, despite my strong reluctance (i very, very, quickly learned how slow it is). the wall is visible, but made of paper. however... ok, that i explain why it's not used everywhere. But now that i know it exist, and that's it's very easy to cyhtonize, back to the question : is there a reason i shouldn't cythonize everything ? some drawback ? something ?

Comment: @kaya3 writing everything in C is much harder than adding 10 line to cythonize pure python.

Comment: @ker2x because at that point you might as well just not be writing Python? If you're going to Cythonize *everything*, just use a different language and spend less time.

Comment: And also, presumably, faster - i.e. it's the same kind of trade-off, just probably not as good, but it is still a trade-off and in most cases "faster" is irrelevant.

Comment: If you improve the running time of a program from 100ms to 10ms but it takes you five minutes to do so - optimistic given you presumably want to test your code as well as write it - then you won't have saved time until you run the program more than a few thousand times. The vast majority of programs are not run that many times.

Comment: If your question is about whether there is a reason *you* in particular shouldn't use Cython for everything, and the extra effort is negligible for the code you write compared to the benefit of faster execution, then the answer is "probably there's no reason you shouldn't".

Comment: @kaya3 Indeed. 90% of what I write in python runs in couple of seconds and/or is IO bound. As for ML/AI, not sure how much of a boost you'll actually get, since those libraries are almost certainly pre-compiled.

Comment: cython can easily surpass numpy in some specific case. while numpy is much faster "per-element" than python, it have a huge call overhead. So it depend. but it's a specific edge case.

Comment: and using numpy is much more difficult to use than simply cythonize some random code